# METEOR on change event only get's fired on a text area after you click out of the text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

Here is my template:

```
<template name="textGoesHere">
{{#if currentUser}}
    <div id="boxdiv">
        <textarea id="box">{{user.text}}</textarea>
    </div>

{{/if}}
</template>
```

Here is my Meteor event:

```
'change #box': function (e) {
        Meteor.call('click', $("#box").val());

}
```

For some reason, this event only gets fired after you click out of the text area after you've changed it's contents. But apparently, the event is suppose to be called when the text area is changed which is the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Um, that is how JavaScript's onchange works in general. The event does not fire until the user leaves the element. If you want something different, you will need to use keypress/input and timers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking to solve a case where a user would paste something into the text area. keypress, timers, and change events don't fire instantaneously after some one pastes.

Comment: So listen for input/paste event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking for the following events if you want to cover your bases for handling that kind of input: `'input change paste keyup mouseup'`

Answer (score 4):

A little more comprehensive (for me) with this :

```
'change #box, paste #box, keyup #box, mouseup #box': function (e) {
        Meteor.call('click', $("#box").val());

}
```